# VS2019 - C# - Exceptions not shown where they are thrown

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've made a small WPF application in .NET Core 3.0 which is giving me this strange behaviour when trying to debug.

The command that's giving me trouble is defined like:

```
public ICommand DoWorkCommand { get; private set; }
```

In the constructor:

```
DoWorkCommand = new CommandHandler(async () => await DoWorkAsync());
```

DoWorkAsync:

```
private async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var logic = new Logic();
    await logic.DoWorkAsync()
}
```

But whatever exception is thrown in the logic class, it's shown in the anonymous method in the initialization of the command.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Could be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231426/async-how-to-break-on-exact-line-of-code-that-has-thrown-the-exception).

Comment: anyway why didn't you add exception handling in `DoWorkAsync` it is last point to catch it

Comment: @DecadeMoon It is, but the answer provided does not solve my problem.